# Possible python refactor?

Tags: python, refactoring, dry

I'm fairly new to python so just looking for help on whether this code block could be refactored. I do need to save separate variables of aCount and bCount for use later on but wondering if it could be simplified

```
def enterA(message):
    while True:
        try:
            global aCount
            aCount = float(input(message))
            assert aCount > 0.00
            break
        except:
            print("Error, enter float")

def enterB(message):
    while True:
        try:
            global bCount
            bCount = float(input(message))
            assert bCount > 0.00
            break
        except:
            print("Error, enter float")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use globals. Don't use `assert` for execution flow logic.

```
def enter_var(message):
    while True:
        try:
            var = float(input(message))
            if var > 0.00:
                return var
        except:
            pass
        print("Error, enter positive float")

a_count = enter_var('Prompt for a')
b_count = enter_var('Prompt for b')
```

1. Having functions rely on one particular global variable defeats their general purpose of reusability.
2. You cannot generally rely on `assert` statements to be actually exectued. Someone who runs your code e.g. in [optimized mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o) via `python -O your_program.py` will have a different result as `asserts` are ignored.

Comment: Thank you, can you please give me more context on why using globals / assert is not good practice?

Comment: This link summarizes it quite well: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-using-the-global-statement-in-Python-a-bad-practice . Note that the arguments against gobals hold for virtually every language.

Comment: Globals make your code hard to read, and you can always express the same logic without them. Mostly they serve to identify migrants from other languages ;-) And `assert` statements are not always executed, that depends on the mode of your interpreter. E.g. if you run `Python -O whatever.py`, they are simply ignored. The core logic of your code should **not** depend on the interpreter mode.

Comment: @r0llie Globals aren't good practice partly for reasons that lead you to ask this question: they make code reliant on a specific variable, so functions that use them aren't as flexible. Global state also makes code harder to understand and maintain. As for why assert shouldn't be used here: you're simply abusing `assert` and exceptions in this code. Use `if` to check a condition. Using `assert` to check a condition, the catching an error with `try` will be slower and less clear than just using an `if`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the helpful information everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def enter_num(message):
    while True:
        try:
            num = float(input(message))
            assert num > 0.00
            return num
        except:
            print("Error, enter float")
message = "Please provide a number:"
aCount = enter_num(message)
bCount = enter_num(message)
```